# how to convert to kotlin window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I convert this code to Kotlin?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
}
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
```

When I tried, the following warning appeared:

> setter for systemUiVisibility: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> 'SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in
> Java

Answer (score 6):

Include dependency `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-alpha05`

Then:

```
WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)?.apply {
    isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
}
```

Comment: If this answer is works for u then please accept the answer.